# Universal definition of Fourier transform

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, ct.category-theory, oc.optimization-and-control

Is there a category theoretic definition for the Fourier transform using only its universality properties? I am not looking for the most general definition -- one that works only in some special settings will do. I am looking for a simple definition that will make precise my (possibly incorrect) intuition that Fourier transforms are in some sense extremal among unitary transforms.

Here is another non category-theoretic way to ask this question, which may or may not be equivalent: Give a "natural" optimization problem on the space of unitary transforms whose solution turns out to be the Fourier transform.

Comment: I assume you're not interested in something like Pontryagin duality.  If that's the case, you might want to edit your question/title accordingly.

Comment: *What* universality properties? What categories do you have in mind?

Comment: -1: This question needs to be made more specific.  Are you looking for a rule that assigns to each locally compact group $A$ a special function on $Isom(L^2(A), L^2(A^\vee))$ that is minimized by the Fourier transform, in a way that is compatible with homomorphisms?

Comment: +1 Often the point of asking a question is not so much to get an answer, but rather to be shown how to improve the question. Fortunately, the above comment does suggests such an improvement, among other things.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. To be honest, I am groping towards the right question. I am perfectly happy working even in finite-dimensional real vector spaces. The degree of generality is not the point (though it would be nice if the definition generalizes.) By universality properties, I mean limits/ colimits of some diagrams in this category. I am trying to get at a definition of the Fourier transform that is "global" in character, and is formulated in a coordinate-free manner. 

Comment: @Chris: I don't agree: at least, I do not think that it's a good kind of question to ask on MO. It's what research supervisors (and teachers) should be there for. Asking vague questions in the hope that someone will suggest the correct version, seems too much like asking other people to do the work, at least on MO.

Comment: @Manoj: you still aren't saying what groups, what L^2-spaces, etc you have in mind. My suggestion is that you edit your question to explain what you mean by the FT in this context -- from *what space* to *what space*? -- and what you regard as a *non-coordinate-free* formulation.

Comment: I think the most generalized definition which preserve the mathematical interests in harmonic analysis is defined over a locally compact abelian group with respect to its Haar mesure.

For more details, H. Reiter's "Classical Harmonic Analysis and Locally Compact Groups" is a good reference. 

Comment: In counter to the previous comment: there is a fairly well-established notion of nonabelian Fourier transform for compact groups (this is in Hewitt & Ross volume 2 but there ought to be easier accounts out there). One can then also get into the whole business of locally compact quantum groups but that is a whole new story...

Comment: The following is a unique, rather than universal, characterization of the FT, but you might like it anyway: Semyon Alesker, Shiri Artstein-Avidan, Vitali Milman, A characterization of the Fourier transform and related topics (http://www.tau.ac.il/~shiri/cras/fourchar.pdf), Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des Sciences I 346 (2008), 625-628.

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant, but Thomas Donaldson's "Harmonic Analysis on Categories of Banach Spaces of Distributions" (http://www.jstor.org/pss/1996428) offers the following:

Definition 1.16 (the Fourier Transform). Let $T^n$ be a toroidal group and $\mathcal{B}$ the category of Banach space. Suppose that $D$ is the distribution functor acting on $\mathcal{B}$. For every Banach space $X \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\lambda \in D(X)$, define $\hat{\lambda}(m) = \lambda(e_m)$ for all $m \in Z^n$, where $e_m$ is the function defined by $e_m(t) = e^{-i \langle m,t \rangle}$.

Comment: Perhaps, one should mention that Gelfand Naimark duality is also one possible generalization of Fourier analysis and Pontryagin duality.

Comment: The author seems to be uninterested in improving a hopelessly vague question.  If you want this reopened, please revise following the "how to ask" page, and flag for moderator attention.

Comment: I found a paper that shows that the Fourier transform of a finite abelian group can be interpreted as an *optimal* quantum measurement, thus, this can be seen as a *extremal* property (I edited my answer).

Yet I wonder something. Pick up the regular representation of a finite group $G$(abelian or not). The Fourier transform is the change of basis that block-diagonalises the regular representation of $G$ into fundamental blocks of *minimal* size (irreps). Isn't this a extremal property somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, the "traditional Fourier Transform" is a **change of basis** of the algebra of functions from a *group* to some chosen field: from the canonical basis to something sometimes called the Fourier Basis. Because the Transform is constructed using the representation theory of the group, it has "natural" generalisations to objects with "similar" representation theory, e.g. it is defined for Hopf algebras.

I always think of the FT as this kind of **duality**. The Fourier Basis have lot's of interesting properties, but I have not seen a definition of it using extremals. It would be very interesting to see that.

A good start would be if someone gives an answer for **finite abelian groups** and finite **non-abelian groups**. Though "non-abelian" groups have a notion of FT, it is not uniquely defined and it is hard to work with it. An "extremal" condition would be enlightening.

---

**Update 14th Dec 2011**

---

Sorry that this comes several months later, but I found that there is "a way" to define  the quantum Fourier transform for **abelian finite groups** using an *extremal* argument. This argument comes from reference [[1](http://lawrenceip.com/papers/hspsdpabstract.html)]  where the Fourier transform is studied as a tool to design measurements in Quantum Computation and proven to be optimal to solve the abelian hidden subgroup problem. Unfortunately, this property does not hold for **non-abelian** quantum Fourier transforms.

More concretely, what it is proven in  [[1](http://lawrenceip.com/papers/hspsdpabstract.html)]  is the following (all definitions I use are defined in this paper):

> > Consider the *hidden subgroup problem* defined for an abelian group $G$, where the hidden subgroup $H$ is chosen uniformly at random from all subgroups of $G$. Given $n$ tensored random coset states (cosets of $H$), then the measurement that **maximises** the probability of correctly identifying the subgroup $H$ is the following:
> >
> > 1. Start on a random coset-state $|x+H\rangle$ for unknown $H$  which is just a uniform quantum superposition over the elements of the coset $x+H$. Cf. [[1](http://lawrenceip.com/papers/hspsdpabstract.html)] for details on how to create these quantum states.
> > 2. Apply the **abelian quantum Fourier transform** of $G$ on this state.
> > 3. Perform a projective measurement.

Taking several outcomes of the above procedure one obtains a generating set of the orthogonal group $H^\perp$ from which the original subgroup $H$ can be recovered solving a system of linear modular equations [[2](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0411037)]. As far as I know these "orthogonal subgroups" are sometimes called [orthogonal complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) in Mathematics.

To sum up, they key ingredient of the above quantum algorithm is the abelian Fourier transform which is used to implement a quantum measurement to solve the hidden subgroup problem  since it maximises the probability of distinguishing the hidden subgroup. In [[1](http://lawrenceip.com/papers/hspsdpabstract.html)] it is shown that the abelian quantum Fourier transform arises as an optimal POVM which is the solution of a semidefinite program. I guess that maybe you could adopt this kind of extremal property as a definition of the Fourier transform for finite abelian groups. **Note**: it is not clear to me that the optimal POVM found in  [[1](http://lawrenceip.com/papers/hspsdpabstract.html)] is *unique* (up to permutations).

Comment: I know I did not answer the question, but I think that even for simpler mathematical objects that the ones you ask it is not obvious that FT can be defined with an optimization problem.